# How to add files to /var/www/html

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, rackspace

I've been working with a WAMP setup on windows, while learning PHP and MySQL. Lately, I wanted to try to put some of my work online and signed up for Rackspace, and I've now set up a LAMP environment for my server with centOS 6.5.

When I worked off of my own WAMP environment, all files were inside wamp/www as the root directory.

Now, I understand that my root directory for my web environment will be /var/www/html.

To be clear, I am logged as root, so I'm not interested in changing permission. I'm simply interested in learning how to add files into this directory, which the existing posts on stackoverflow or rackspace does not seem to have an answer for.

I'm completely new to Linux and I'm using Putty to write to my linux server. Could someone please walk me through the process of putting files into and taking files out of /var/www/html?

Comment: What do you mean ? Can't you just copy files from one folder to /var/www/html using the console ? Do you get a specific error, or is your question just about using mv/cp comands ?

Comment: Do you want to have a full tutorial on how to use Linux? Or 'cd' command? or sftp?

Comment: I think I've already mentioned that I'm completely new to linux, so I expect to run into really basic problems. Would you mind pointing me to the right direction?\

Comment: We don't understand what is you problem. Are the files you need on your computer and you want to transfer them to the server ? Are the files on the server and you want to know how to move them to `/var/www/html` ? Is it something else ? If it is one of the first 2 cases, there are **plenty** of simple answers and tutorials on google (for instance : with [this](https://www.google.fr/search?q=transfer+file+to+linux+server&oq=transfer+file+to+linux+server) querry I found [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/55846-newbie-question-how-transfer-files-remote-linux-box.html) in 10s)

Comment: The files are on my comp (I'm using windows) and I want to move them to the server. I already know how to do this with Filezilla and wanted to learn how to do it through the command line.

Comment: @Ploutox I checked your links and they're helping me. I see you had a more generic search for how to move any file. For some reason I had decided to search about /var/www/html specifically, which yielded much less results for me. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pscp from the putty suite, to copy your files from your machine to the server via scp.

See http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html